# How to disable code analysis in Visual Studio 2022 Preview?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, visual-studio-2022, stylecop

I read https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-quality/analyzers-faq#code-analysis-solution-property-page

[image]

[image]

but in my Visual Studio 2022 Preview, I cannot use it. How to disable Code Analysis without GUI or other way?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue and my visual studio community version is Version 17.1.3. Not found any solution for it yet which is causing lot of trouble

Answer (score 2):

I just got the solution for it in VS2022. Go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Advance-> Remove check box for following

- Enable Pull Diagnostic (Experimental, require restart)
- Enable Razor Pull..
- Run Code Analysis..

After doing this this long pending get resolved for me